# Erlang global PID - how to save it in MySQL

Tags: erlang

Problem : I have multiple Erlang services, each of them identified by their Erlang PID. I'd like to save {PID, ServiceName} in my database (MySQL) in such a way that any Erlang process in my cluster that needs to access any service will just need to SELECT for the service name to get its PID and then do a gen_server call to it.

1. the PID should be saved after I converted it to a "global" PID with term_to_binary(self()) - basically, imagine Erlang process A on Node1 saving itself as <0.45.0> in the db: this means that process B on Node2 trying to access the service represented by <0.45.0> will not succeed since "<0.45.0>" is valid only on Node1; saving it as PID = term_to_binary(self()) will correctly decode to the global PID if we run binary_to_term(PID) on Node2 when we read it from the db
2. the MySQL query is formatted with "INSERT INTO ServiceTable ... " ++ io_lib:format("ServicePID = '~p', " [binary_to_list(term_to_binary(self()))]) ++
3. when I read the PID back from the db, I get something like <<"[131,103,100,0,23,115"...>> and this is where my problem is : can I convert this binary back to something like <<131, 103, 100, etc ... >> ???

(I KNOW I could workaround this problem by for example registering my services, etc - but I have my reasons not to do that).

Thank you.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you think carefully about why you think you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you show, I guess that you could avoid the transformation from  binary to list, so the io_lib:format will transform the binary into a string representation of it.

Later you can retrieve the pid using the erl_parse and erl_eval modules:

```
1> Pid = self(). 
<0.32.0>
2> 
2> String = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p.~n",[term_to_binary(Pid)])).
"<<131,103,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,111,104,111,115,116,0,0,0,32,\n  0,0,0,0,0>>.\n"
3> %% to get an equivalent form of what you get from sql.
3> {done,{ok,T,_},[]} = erl_scan:tokens([],String,1).
{done,{ok,[{'<<',1},
           {integer,1,131},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,103},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,100},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,0},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,13},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,110},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,111},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,110},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,111},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,100},
           {',',1},
           {integer,1,101},
           {',',1},
           {integer,...},
           {...}|...],
          3},
      []}
4> {ok,Tree} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(T).
{ok,[{bin,1,
          [{bin_element,1,{integer,1,131},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,103},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,100},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,0},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,13},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,110},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,111},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,110},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,111},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,100},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,101},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,64},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,110},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,111},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,104},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,111},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,115},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,1,...},default,default},
           {bin_element,1,{integer,...},default,...},
           {bin_element,1,{...},...},
           {bin_element,1,...},
           {bin_element,...},
           {...}|...]}]}
5> {value,Res,[]} = erl_eval:exprs(Tree,[]).
{value,<<131,103,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,
         111,104,111,115,116,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,0,0>>,
       []}
6> Pid =  binary_to_term(Res).  %% that's it :o)
<0.32.0>
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer to my problem. Thank you, Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pre-existing solution, such as [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) (by Ulf Wiger).

I saw a similar solution recently at ErlangFactory 2015, by [martinsk](https://github.com/martinsk?tab=repositories) that he said may be released soon called "Industry". It did more than gproc, including features like raft consensus protocol support to determine the best server to take the lead ... more related to his use case, I suppose.

Gproc is likely your best first step. The configuration and caching options might give you the support you need to physically store the data, if you were using MySQL for something more than just a knowledge base of global registrations.

But, to also answer your specific question, and if you really want to do this yourself, maybe `atom_to_list(node()) ++ pid_to_list(self()).` could work.

e.g.:

`(foo@lankhmar)6> atom_to_list(node()) ++ pid_to_list(self()). 
"foo@lankhmar<0.43.0>"`

Comment: I looked at gproc, but it doesn't handle netspliting. Also, __all__ my nodes need to be up __before__ I start using gproc.

Comment: @user3479863 This whole line of discourse is heading a place you shouldn't be headed; an illustrative case of an XY problem in action. This statement, "[gproc] doesn't handle netsplitting", says it all.

Comment: @zxq9 - I agree with you, I am falling into an XY problem. I will take your earlier advice and __strongly__ think about why do I need this. BTW, some of my problems with using gproc are described here : [Erlang gproc failure semantics](http://christophermeiklejohn.com/erlang/2013/06/05/erlang-gproc-failure-semantics.html). I will ask another, clearer, question on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use [pid_to_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#pid_to_list-1) and [list_to_pid/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_pid-1) functions.

Comment: let's say I'm on Node1 and self() returns <0.45.0> - pid_to_list(self()) will save "<0.45.0>" in the db and if a process on Node2 reads it back and tries to send a message to <0.45.0>, it will fail because <0.45.0> is an ID that's valid ONLY on Node1 - you need to do term_to_binary(self()) in order for Node2 to understand where the PID is located.